# How to automatically join a squad when joining a server

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

When I played BF3 initially I recall always joining a squad when joining a server. I just got the first patch and I no longer do that. How do I configure Battlefield 3 such that I join a squad automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They actually took this feature [completely out](http://blogs.battlefield.ea.com/battlefield_bad_company/archive/2011/11/21/multiple-fixes-and-new-squad-functionality-in-today-s-pc-patch-for-battlefield-3.aspx##).  I don't think everyone is [happy](http://www.overclock.net/t/1172370/what-in-gods-name-did-they-do-to-battlefield-3) about it, so it's possible that it might come back in the future, or get readded via a mod.  For now, though, you'll just have to work around it.

Comment: what they need to add back is the "automatically join a squad" checkbox they had on the Battlefield 2: Bad Company (and I think BF2 too?) level loading screens!

Comment: @JeffAtwood It is on the loading screen on PS3. Are you on PC? If so, question should be tagged accordingly as problem doesn't exist on PS3 (we cannot use battlelog to join games obviously)